# How to get request URL with Request.Path.Substring

Tags: asp.net, url, url-rewriting

I have a URL like : `http://localhost.com/Dometic-Tou/french-with-flights-milano-10-12-may-2014.html`

How can ı get this text from the URL : `Domestic-Tou`

I have got the link but all I want just `Domestic-Tou` from the link

I have tried:

```
Request.Path.Substring(Request.Path.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use ***Request.substring***. It will not give the expected result which you require. Instead use this.

```
string [] test = link.Split('/');

string required_subpart = test[3].ToString();
```

**Note: the index is 3 here. Why because the url contains http://. So if you do not have http:// in your url, the index would be 1. Substitute it with whatever part you want in a url.**

Let me know if this works for you, or I have an alternate solution for you.

Comment: I cant do it with this way , I want to second alternative solution thx

Comment: I have done with this answer thx , I wonder the second alternative solition ? could you tell me ?

Comment: Please up vote the answer if its right. I will share the alternate solution shortly. Are you getting the url from Request.URL paramater?

Comment: I voted up but it give to me this error Vote Up requires 15 reputation - Yes , get the url by `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString();`